# iPhone - GCD check if queue is suspended

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have to use `dispatch_resume(...);` to resume a dispatch that was suspended, but as the method resuming the dispatch may be called by several parts of the app, I need to know if the dispatch is suspended before calling it to resume (the docs says I have to balance dispatch resume/suspend and cannot have more resumes than suspends, or I will end with a "negative suspension counter".

Is there a way to do test if a dispatch is suspended?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is not, by design (and just like there is no cancellation mechanism).   The notion of suspend/resume must be balanced every bit as carefully as retain/release

That is, if A suspends the queue, there is no way for B to safely know that it can resume the queue without intimate knowledge of A.  Given that, there is no reason for the dispatch APIs to add the complexity of is-suspended queries and enable a whole class of bugs that would crop up all over the place.

Comment: In Swift 3/iOS 10, seems there is a cancel mechanism (`.cancel()`)...is there still no way to check if a `DispatchSourceTimer` is suspended? Thanks!

Comment: @DanRosenstark Nope, still not (Swift 5.5, iOS15).